# How to diagnose high self time in VisualVM?

Tags: java, algorithm, profiler, visualvm, cpu-time

I am trying to implement an algorithm using different data structure implementations to see their difference, and noticed that for the exact same algorithm using a different data structure, the "Self Time" in the algorithm method is very high.

Is there a way in VisualVM to investigate why Self Time is high in a method, given that the algorithm is implemented exactly the same way with just a different data structure? (To make it even more perplexing, the method with high Self Time has much lower CPU time to use its data structure. I don't know why time in the algorithm itself is so much higher.)

Comment: One cool debugging trick that always works is to step by step remove the differences between the two algorithms. As you turn 1 algorithm into the other , you should find the step the makes the difference.

Comment: The method with the high self time may be executing a sleep, a wait, a file IO, more synchronization wait time than the other method. It is not unusual for such a method to have low CPU time and high total time.

Comment: @GonenI Thanks for the tip! I'm actually looking at the CPU time instead of the wall-clock time, so that's probably not the case here...

Comment: Then refactor your code to break the problematic method into smaller methods to find out which part is the slow one.